# My Spinner is not working

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a `spinner` and it is not working , I have created it with the tab, on clicking the tab icon I want to get the drop down list,but now on clicking the icon the application suddenly getting closed saying an error with a null pointer exception I'm sure I am missing something stupid ! I am giving my logcat and java class below
I need suggestions to clear the error.

```
08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        
activity ComponentInfo{com.neochat/com.neochat.ComposeActivity}:  
java.lang.NullPointerException

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at  
android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
com.neochat.ComposeActivity.onCreate(ComposeActivity.java:29)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

08-27 04:59:49.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     ... 18 more
```

### ComposeActivity.java

```
              public class ComposeActivity extends Activity {

             /** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
             String[] actions = new String[] {
            "Bookmark",
             "Subscribe",
             "Share"
             };
              Context context;
             /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
              public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.extrasettings);
                 Spinner mySpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
               context=this;

           /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);

            /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
            getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

            /** Defining Navigation listener */
             ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new
              OnNavigationListener() {

           @Override
             public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition] 
              , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
                }
               };

           /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
                getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
               }
               }
```

**my XML file where I have added my spinner**

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" 
                   >

             <Spinner
              android:id="@+id/spinner1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

             </LinearLayout>
```

**I have used a simple tab option not an action bar on my application so is there any problem.... Excuse me I want to add the spinner to my tabhost so can anybody tell me what changes should I make in the code please?**

Comment: Can you please provide the 'complete' Logs ?

Comment: There should be a line in `Logcat` that shows where the error happens at your which line of code. Please post the complete `Logcat`

Comment: It is very crucial to see the line number of Exception.

Comment: ok hold on a second...

Comment: did you added ComposeActivity in your manifest.xml?

Comment: yeah I have added the activity in manifest.xml

Comment: @Shobhit : I have given my complete logcat above please check

Comment: post your  xml and reaming code of ComposeActivity where  you set adapter

Comment: at which line right now occured error after updated your code.

Comment: What is the api of the device you are running the code on?

Comment: I am using an emulator and using the min sdk version ="14" and target sdk version="22"

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is a **null pointer exception**. Please debug and check whether you have written

```
Spinner mySpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

and the value of "actions" is not null.

Comment: I have added it now but still pointing the null pointer exception

Comment: Have you added this line?? mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: Can you please debug your application and find out in which line you are getting the exception??

Comment: Can you please check this???                       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, actions); dataAdapter
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

instantiate mySpinner inside the onCreate method.